# Set stock levels on the configurable products

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, stock

As we all know when you have a configurable product such as a T-Shirt in blue and red, you would create 2 simple products and 1 configurable product and each simple product would have its own stock level as you have a certain number of red t-shirts and a certain number of blue t-shirts.

My issue is that I want to sell cans in either singles or multiple of 10's but deduct from the same stock. Therefore ideally I would like to set up a configurable product in the normal way but for the stock level to be set at the configurable product level rather than the simple product level. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about using product custom options instead of configurable products? Would that work for your use case?

/Edit: to answer your question, it's not possible to do that with Magento out of the box. You would need to look for an extension to do that or develop it yourself.

/Edit2: Here's a link to Magento's documentation with more information about Custom Options:http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-options-custom.html%3FTocPath%3DProduct%2520Catalog%7CProduct%2520Information%7C_____11

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I cant use product custom options as when a customer buys cans in multiple of 10s it only deducts the stock level by 1 instead of of multiples of 10s.... Unless I am doing something wrong?

Comment: In that case maybe Grouped Products get you closer to what you want: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-grouped.html although there may be some inconveniences, as you can see in the "Things to remember" section.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but with Grouped Products I think I am going to have the same issue as the stock level is at the simple product level

Comment: Ok, then I might have not understood the question. Do you want to sell a single SKU in quantities that are multiple of X, 10 in this case, or do you want to sell multiple SKUs but deduct stock from a single place, basically shared stock for several SKUs?

Comment: I want to sell multiple skus but deduct stock from a single place

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what the products' custom options do: you can sell a variation of skus and deduct stock from a single place. Now, in your first comment you were saying something about multiples of 10s. Can you please tell me how you're doing that, buying multiples of 10s?

Answer (score 0):

By design, a configurable product itself has no stock, so you would have to change inner workings of Magento in lots of places.

So I would rather try to find a solution that just changes the frontend, and not use product types for things they were not intended for.

For example: Add a "package size" dropdown to the "add to cart" template, next to the qty input, with the values 1 and 10. Add a second qty input and make the actual qty input a hidden field. Then calculate the value of the hidden field with JavaScript.

To make this more flexible, you can show these modified inputs only if the product has a certain custom attribute set, and also define the possible package sizes with a custom attribute.

If you use this approach, pay attention to the "edit cart item" page, where the qty field is prepopulated. You'd have to set the new package size and package qty inputs based on the preset qty on load.